# Ruby frozen string literal pragma order caused error

Tags: ruby, ruby-2.3

Given a file with Ruby 2.3.0p0:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

# frozen_string_literal: true

# Exit cleanly from an early interrupt
Signal.trap("INT") { abort }
```

This is fine.

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

#!/usr/bin/env ruby

# Exit cleanly from an early interrupt
Signal.trap("INT") { abort }
```

will result in error:

```
syntax error near unexpected token `"INT"'
`Signal.trap("INT") { abort }'
```

Why?

Comment: how are you executing the file - ./filename.rb or ruby filename.rb ?

Comment: That is no Ruby error, it's from your shell. The [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) has to be the initial line. Otherwise, the file is executed as a shell script.

Comment: @Stefan Could you post it as an answer? Thanks.

Comment: Why does the error point to line 8 when there are only six lines?

Comment: Following this question, I asked a related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36065453

Comment: @sawa Sorry this is copied from a script, the number is not important, edited my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) has to appear on the file's initial line.

A file `test.rb` containing:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby    
# foo bar
puts "hello from #{RbConfig.ruby}"
```

will be run via Ruby:

```
$ ./test.rb
hello from /.../ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby
```

But if `test.rb` contains: (1st and 2nd line swapped)

```
# foo bar
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
echo "hello from $SHELL"
```

it will be run as an ordinary shell script:

```
$ ./test.rb
hello from /.../bin/zsh
```

Therefore, the error you are getting is no Ruby error, it's from your shell.