# Within how many lines from the beginning do various directions have to be placed?

Tags: ruby, unix, vim, emacs

There are various directions following a comment character `#` that are interpreted in a specific way.

- UNIX shebang: `#!/usr/bin/env ruby`
- magic comment for encoding (used in Ruby 1.9): `#coding: UTF-8`
- frozen string literal pragma: `#frozen_string_literal: true`
- ruby-mode direction for text editors (like emacs): `#!ruby`
- vim encoding direction: `#vim:set fileencoding=euc-jp`

It is clear that they have to be placed near the beginning of the file to work correctly, but when there are more than one of them, they cannot all be placed on the first line. Within how many lines from the beginning of the file do they have to be placed? Is the relative order between them relevant? What are the rules that decide them?

If there are other than those I listed above, please add that.

Comment: In the specific case of the Vim modeline, it doesn't actually *need* to be at the top; Vim checks the first five *and* last five lines of a file (although this number is configurable with the `modelines` setting)... The hashbang *needs* to be on the first line... I don't know about all the others... (...this is a bit of a broad question...)

Comment: That are actually four question, because the lines are interpreted by different programs (shell, ruby, emacs and vim).

Comment: @Stefan The shell doesn't look at the hashbang, this is a linker and/or kernel feature (I'm not sure where it's implemented *exactly*, and this may vary per system, but it's most certainly not the shell).

Comment: @Carpetsmoker yes, that was inaccurate.

Comment: Emacs doesn't need/want a `#!ruby` thingy, instead it recognizes the `#!/usr/bin/ruby` line or a `# -*- ruby -*-` (which can be on the second line at most and only if the first is a #!, IIRC).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*(This is a community wiki answer. It's incomplete, so please add your findings.)*

---

#### `#!/usr/bin/env ruby`

- [UNIX shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix))
- Must appear at the left margin on the first line of a shell script
- Interpreted by kernel, some text editors use it to determine the file type

#### `#coding: UTF-8`

- Magic comment for encoding
- Must appear on the first line or on the second line if the first line is a shebang but can be formatted loosely, e.g. `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`
- Interpreted by Ruby 1.9+

#### `#frozen_string_literal: true`

- Frozen string literal pragma
- Appearance?
- Interpreted by Ruby 2.3

#### `# -*- mode: ruby -*-`

- Emacs file-local variables
- Must appear on the first line or on the second line if the first line is a shebang
- Interpreted by Emacs

#### `#vim:set fileencoding=euc-jp`

- Vim modeline
- Must appear within the first five or last five lines, although this number is configurable with the `modelines` setting
- Interpreted by Vim if the `modeline` setting is enabled (on by default except for `root`).

Comment: The frozen string literal pragma has actually been fairly well specified, which is (unfortunately) rather unusual in the Ruby community. I specifically remember that the lines where it can appear and under what circumstances are explicitly mentioned in that document. I don't remember where it was, though. It might have been the 2.3 release notes, 2.3 changelog, or the feature request discussion on the Ruby issue tracker.

Comment: The encoding pragma was specifically designed such that Emacs and Vim modelines are also legal Ruby encoding pragmas.

Comment: I believe, but cannot verify at the moment, that the encoding pragma *must* be the first line after an (optional) shebang, and the frozen string literal pragma *must* be the first line after an optional shebang and/or an optional encoding pragma. I'm not sure about whether or not empty lines are allowed in between.

Comment: I can confirm that the “Frozen String Literal Pragma.” works on the second line if first is shebang. Have not checked other options.